# Как работает функция numpy.dot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Помогите разобраться с функцией  `numpy.dot`. Как то не очень понятно описание в документации. Эта функция работает так же как описано в [этой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86) статье?

Есть следующий код:

```
Nj   = 100
Nin = 100

Xin = np.zeros((Nin,1))
Winj = np.zeros((Nin,Nj))

WinjT  = np.transpose(Winj)
Uj = np.dot(WinjT,Xin)
```

По идее должен получиться массив Uj с числом строк Nj и 1 столбцом, но получается двумерный массив.
 Часть кода идущая после инициализации прощена, так как не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: Эта функция - скалярное произведение, если в нее передали вектора и произведение матриц (самое обыкновенное), если передали матрицы.

Comment: Я так понимаю под вектором подразумевается одномерный массив, а под матрицей двухмерный. Или же необходимо определять матрицы функцией numpy.matrix?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

произведение скаляров:

```
In [60]: np.dot(2, 3)
Out[60]: 6
```

произведение 1D массивов (векторов):

```
In [61]: a = np.array([1, 2])

In [62]: b = np.array([10, 11])

In [63]: np.dot(a, b)
Out[63]: 32
```

произведение 2D массивов:

```
In [64]: a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])

In [65]: b = np.array([[2,3], [4,5]])

In [66]: a
Out[66]:
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [67]: b
Out[67]:
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

In [68]: np.dot(a, b)
Out[68]:
array([[10, 13],
       [22, 29]])
```

Пояснение:

```
10: 1*2 + 2*4
13: 1*3 + 2*5

22: 3*2 + 4*4
29: 3*3 + 4*5
```

Ваш пример:

```
In [69]: %paste
Nj   = 100
Nin = 100

Xin = np.zeros((Nin,1))
Winj = np.zeros((Nin,Nj))

WinjT  = np.transpose(Winj)
Uj = np.dot(WinjT,Xin)

## -- End pasted text --
```

Получился 2D массив, состоящий из 100 строк и одного столбца:

```
In [70]: Uj.shape
Out[70]: (100, 1)
```